# javascript - get attribute value by text value

Tags: javascript, jquery

`<a href='http://example.com'>Goes To Example.com</a>`

I want to get the href value of this. This link will always be on the page

I will usually do something like: `document.getElementsByTagName('a')[5]`. However, the number of links are always changing so it isn't reliable at all. Is there a way I can get it by the text `Goes To Example.com`?

Comment: Is JQuery an option?

Comment: Yes I can use jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said in comment you can use jquery, use [*Contains*](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) like bellow

```
$('a:contains("Goes To Example.com")')
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/95/)

Comment: Keeps returning null for some reason

Comment: @JosephSala try once `$('a:contains(Goes To Example.com)')` no quotes in contains, in demo both works

Comment: Still returns null, works in fiddle but not on localhost

Comment: My bad, I forgot to include jQuery. All good solutions but this one was simplest.

Answer (score 1):

You could use xpath:

```
document.evaluate(
    '/html/body//a[text()='Goes To Example.com']/@href', 
    document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

You can iterate over the result (which is of type `XPathResult`) using `iterateNext`.

See xpath documentation for details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.evaluate.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Sorry, I used `...` at the end to indicate parameters that you needed to fill in. I've now given the full statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use the JQuery :contains() selector.  You can then get the attribute "href", as follows:

```
$("a:contains(Goes To Example.com)").attr("href");
```

For example, the following snippet will popup an alert with `http://example.com` inside it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href='http://example.com'>Goes To Example.com</a>

        <script>
            alert($("a:contains(Goes To Example.com)").attr("href"));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do document.getElementById and give the id to the a tag. To get the text you can use innerHTML function

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1m2hLfrm/)

HTML Markup

```
<a id="test" href='http://example.com'>Goes To Example.com</a>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML
```

If you want it by href attribute only then you have to loop it over

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
    var el = els[i];
    if (el.href === 'http://www.example.com/') {
        alert(el.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Comment: He mentioned to get id value based on its text value, not by its herf value. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var requiredId = "";
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
    if(links[i].innerHTML == "Goes To Example.com"){
        requiredId = links[i].getAttribute('id');
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it different from my answer?

Comment: Here, if 'a' elements's text is equal to 'Goes To Example.com' then am taking its attribute value. But, not href based. This is what question author has mentioned. Please check it once in question.